# How can I select the first occurence of each checkbox that has a unique value for a specific attribute using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Hard question to understand, I'm sure, so I'll show you what I'm trying to do:

Let's say I have the following checkboxes HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" /> Select All
<input type="checkbox" name="addressId" value="100" uid="1" /> Address 100
<input type="checkbox" name="addressId" value="101" uid="2" /> Address 101
<input type="checkbox" name="addressId" value="102" uid="3" /> Address 102
<input type="checkbox" name="addressId" value="103" uid="4" /> Address 103
<input type="checkbox" name="addressId" value="104" uid="2" /> Address 104
<input type="checkbox" name="addressId" value="105" uid="4" /> Address 105
<input type="checkbox" name="addressId" value="106" uid="5" /> Address 106
```

I am currently using the following Select All jQuery logic:

```
$("#selectAll").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
        $("input[name='addressId']").attr("checked", "").removeAttr("checked").attr("checked", "checked");
    else
        $("input[name='addressId']").attr("checked", "").removeAttr("checked");
});
```

Basically, I need to update this logic so that only the ***FIRST*** checkbox of each set of checkboxes that has a matching `uid` value (for eaxmple, address 101 and 104 have a matching `uid` value -2) is selected. So, in the above example, only Address Ids 100, 101, 102, 103, AND 106 would be selected, and 104 and 105 would remain unselected. How I can do this in jQuery? I just can't seem to figure out the selector!

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer, but a handy performance tip: use `this.checked` instead of `$(this).is(":checked")`.  Other than that I don't understand your question, but `attr("checked", "").removeAttr("checked").attr("checked", "checked")` seems like the most pointless piece of code ever :-)

Comment: I don't understand the question either. What logic leads you to decide you only want to go through 103 and not to the end? You can select a subset of matched elements with `.slice()` but you're probably looking for something more than just picking the first x items.

Comment: What do you mean by `matching value of uid`? Matches what?

Comment: @Guttsy, this is just sample/pseudo-code. When I click "Select All", I want to select all from the ENTIRE set of checkboxes, but only the first of each "set" of checkboxes that has a matching attribute value. In my example, it just so happens that 103 is the last checkbox that has a unique "uid" value.

Comment: @Joseph - matches values of uid in the other checkboxes. For example, for address 101 and 104, the "uid" value matches. Perhaps equals makes more sense???

Comment: @Eric Sorry, I'm still confused. (Maybe someone else will catch on?) What role does UID serve here?  Oh, and if you want to make your change function (as shown above) dead simple: `$("input[name='addressId']").attr("checked",this.checked)
});`

Comment: Matches/equals WHAT??? Are you saying you want to only check a checkbox if there's another checkbox with the same `uid`, but only the first one of the two?

Comment: Looks like it got clarified in an answer below... and in the original post.

Comment: The number of answers in this thread sticking with `$(this).is(":checked")` is deeply disturbing.  See http://jsperf.com/stop-writing-this-is-checked and http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/utilizing-the-awesome-power-of-jquery-to-access-properties-of-an-element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way of getting the checkboxes, but it works:

```
var uids = [],
    unique = $('input[name=addressId]').filter(function(index) {
        var uid = $(this).attr('uid');
        if ($.inArray(uid, uids) == -1) {
            uids.push(uid);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

So then, you could simplify the event handler on `#selectAll` as:

```
$('#selectAll').change(function() {
    unique.attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/crkA7/

Comment: That is comically more elegant than my solution.

Comment: +1 This works. Was trying to avoid a loop, but this is good - simple and concise.

Comment: I know. Unfortunately, there's no unique attribute selector in jQuery, so a loop is unavoidable. However, I don't think you're going to see a noticeable performance hit, even with more controls than are in this example.

Comment: This answer actually helped me understand the question. Hopefully you actually mark it as the answer and not just +1. Deserves more credit.

Comment: Works great - had to tweak it a little bit to deal with my dynamic form (hiding items based on filters, etc.). Marked as answer.

Comment: FYI, I had to edit this to use $.inArray() instead of array.indexOf(), because that bombed on me in IE.

Comment: @Eric: beware that this won't work in IE8 and lower without the compatibility implementation of [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility).  (edit) `$.inArray` works pretty much the same as you discovered.  Also, once again `$(this).is(":checked")` bad.  `this.checked` good.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this'll do the job:

```
$("#selectAll").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        var checkedUids = [];
        $("input[name='addressId']").each(function(){
           var $this = $(this);
           if(checkedUids.indexOf($this.attr('uid')) == -1)
           {
              $this.attr("checked","checked");
             checkedUids.push(  $this.attr('uid') );
           }
        });
    }  
    else
        $("input[name='addressId']").attr("checked", "").removeAttr("checked");
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/mJvHa/

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#selectAll").change(function() {

    var $inputs = $("input[name='addressId']"),
        state = this.checked,
        UIDs = [];

    $.each($inputs.toArray().reverse(), function()
    {
        if ( $.inArray($(this).attr('uid'), UIDs) != -1 )
            $(this).prop('checked', state);
        else
            UIDs.push( $(this).attr('uid') );
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YEbD2/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

Working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j9m7P/2/)**

```
$("#selectAll").change(function() {
    if (this.checked){
        $("input[name='addressId']").each(function(i){
           if(i == 0 || $("input[name='addressId']").filter(":lt("+i+")").filter(")[uid="+$(this).attr('uid')+"]").length == 0){
              this.checked = true;
           }
            else{
                this.checked = false;
            } 
        });
    }
    else{
        $("input[name='addressId']").attr("checked", false).removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```

Comment: @Eric - Take a look at the demo it exactly works as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$("#selectAll").change(function() {
if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    $("input[name='addressId']").filter('[uid=' + specific_uid_value + ']').first().attr("checked", "").removeAttr("checked").attr("checked", "checked");
else
    $("input[name='addressId']").filter('[uid=' + specific_uid_value + ']').first()..attr("checked", "").removeAttr("checked");
});
```

where `specific_uid_value` is the  `uid` value that you want to filter.

the jQuery filter function will filter the checkboxes with attribute uid = your desider value and the jQUery first function will give you the first checkbox that fulfill the requirements.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I'm not filtering by a specific value. I want to select the first of each "set" of checkboxes with equal `uid` values.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it, but I feel like it could be better. After the conditional, loop through the inputs and uncheck any duplicates.

```
$("#selectAll").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
        $("input[name='addressId']").attr("checked", "").removeAttr("checked").attr("checked", "checked");
    else
        $("input[name='addressId']").attr("checked", "").removeAttr("checked");

    var uids = new Array();

    $("input[name='addressId']").each(function(){
        if (jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('uid'), uids))
            $(this).removeAttr("checked");
        else
            uids($(this).attr('uid'));
    });
});
```